# How to rolling-window aggregate but keep the unique index column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to rolling-window aggregate a dataframe, but it is crucial that my result keeps a column with a unique index, because later I want to join my aggregation back into the original dataframe.

So like

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
   {"id": range(6),
    "t": [pd.Timestamp("2019-01-01")+dt.timedelta(seconds=sec) for sec in [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
    "gr": list("ababab"),
    "val": range(6)})

agg = df.groupby("gr").rolling("2s", on="t")["val"].sum()  # <- id not present anymore
```

Now I'd like to join `agg` back into `df` on `id` but unfortunately Pandas `rolling` made `t` the level of the multi-index. (Time `t` is actually not unique)

Is there any way I can get `id` in `agg` ?

Looking at

```
>>> df.sort_values(["gr", "t"])
   id                   t gr  val
2   3 2019-01-01 00:00:01  a    2
4   1 2019-01-01 00:00:01  a    4
0   5 2019-01-01 00:00:02  a    0
3   2 2019-01-01 00:00:01  b    3
5   0 2019-01-01 00:00:01  b    5
1   4 2019-01-01 00:00:02  b    1
```

the expected sum should be

```
   id                   t gr  sum_val
2   3 2019-01-01 00:00:01  a    2
4   1 2019-01-01 00:00:01  a    6
0   5 2019-01-01 00:00:02  a    6
3   2 2019-01-01 00:00:01  b    3
5   0 2019-01-01 00:00:01  b    8
1   4 2019-01-01 00:00:02  b    9
```

However, the output of one suggested solution is

```
agg = df.sort_values("t").groupby(['gr']).rolling("2s", on="t")['val'].sum().reset_index(name='sum_val')
agg['id'] = df.sort_values(['gr'])['id'].values
agg.sort_values(["gr", "t"])
```

Output:

```
  gr                   t  sum_val  id
0  a 2019-01-01 00:00:01      2.0   5
1  a 2019-01-01 00:00:01      6.0   3
2  a 2019-01-01 00:00:02      6.0   1
3  b 2019-01-01 00:00:01      3.0   4
4  b 2019-01-01 00:00:01      8.0   2
5  b 2019-01-01 00:00:02      9.0   0
```

`gr='a'`, `id=5` should be 6 though?!

UPDATE: I made the time more duplicate to demonstrate the problem.
UPDATE: Made `t` a time column because before it wasnt doing what it was supposed to do.

Comment: what about doing `agg.reset_index()`?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting since it doesn't look very meaningful to associate an `id` with a rolling across sum other id's.

Comment: I adjusted the example to make the time non-unique within the groups. That's where the issue comes from.

Comment: @QuangHoang I need my rolling aggregation back in the original dataframe somehow. And that should be a meaningful operation? The id is only to find the right spot.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
df['roll'] = (df.groupby("gr", as_index=False, group_keys=False)
                .apply(lambda x: x.rolling(2, on='t')['val'].sum())
             )
```

Output:

```
   id  t gr  val  roll
0   0  1  a    0   NaN
1   1  1  b    1   NaN
2   2  1  a    2   2.0
3   3  1  b    3   4.0
4   4  2  a    4   6.0
5   5  2  b    5   8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `t` is non unique within a group but `id` is unique and you are grouping on `gr`, you can do:

```
agg = df.groupby(['gr']).rolling(2, on="t")['val'].sum().reset_index(name='sum_val')
agg['id'] = df.sort_values(['gr'])['id'].values
```

Output:

```
    gr  t   sum_val id
0   a   1   NaN 0
1   a   1   2.0 2
2   a   2   6.0 4
3   b   1   NaN 1
4   b   1   4.0 3
5   b   2   8.0 5
```

If `t` is unique, you can do:

You can merge back with original df

```
df.groupby(['gr']).rolling(2, on="t")['val'].sum().reset_index(name='sum_val').merge(df[['id', 't', 'gr']])
```

Output:

```
    gr  t   sum_val id
0   a   1   NaN      0
1   a   2   2.0      2
2   a   3   6.0      4
3   b   1   NaN      1
4   b   2   4.0      3
5   b   3   8.0      5
```

Comment: Oh right. But I realize my problem comes from the time being non-unique even within the groups. I adjusted my example. Then I cannot join unambiguously anymore?!

Comment: Updated my answer. @Gerenuk

Comment: But `b` had ids 1,3,5 before and now it has 3,4,5 in your first example?

Comment: @Gerenuk, forgot to take `id` as an array. With the series, it goes with original indexes, which would be wrong. Fixed that. (`.values`)

Comment: I realize Pandas didnt do what I wanted and didnt warn me either. The `on` is ineffective. And if I change `t` to time and the window to `"2s"` Pandas calculates incorrectly without warning. But once you realize that and you presort on `t`, your sorting trick can be made working again.

Comment: ... hmm no. I was wrong. The order is messed up and the result incorrect with the version above :( Best checked by looking at `df.sort_values(["gr", "t"])`

Comment: How is it incorrect? Can you show expected output in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Just found this alternative solution:

```py
agg = df.groupby("gr").rolling(2)["val"].sum().droplevel(0)

result = df.assign(sum_val=agg)
```

Without the `on="t"` on `rolling`, this will index `agg` on the index of the dataframe.
Then we must use `droplevel` to remove the `gr` group from the index, which is added by the `groupby`.